# How can you enable/disable collisions in unreal Physics Editor while using python?

Tags: python, scripting, physics-engine, unreal

Is it possible to use Python to get the selected order in the Unreal Physics Editor, and have all the first selected collision shape enable collisions with all the subsequent collisions?

[image]

I want to have Capsule 1 apply collisions to Capsules 2, 3, 4, 5 but without applying collisions to each other.

I'm currently using Unreal 4.26